# Get an Array from data in cloud function ("TypeError: data.filters.forEach is not a function")

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, google-cloud-functions

When I call the "cloud function" from my Android application, the Firebase console gives me the following error:

```
Error getting documents TypeError: data.filters.forEach is not a function
    at admin.database.ref.once.then (/user_code/index.js:63:26)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal / process / next_tick.js: 135: 7)
```

I try several options to deal with the array that I send from the application, but I can not make it work

```
exports.filter = functions.https.onCall((data, response) => {
    return admin.database().ref(Constants.RESTOS_EXCEL).once("value")
        .then((snapshot) => {
            var restos = [];
            var arrayToCompare = data.filters;

            snapshot.forEach((restoSnap) => {
                var restoKey = restoSnap.key;
                var resto = restoSnap.val();

                var isRestoFiltered = false;

                //fields
                var fields = [];
                fields.push(resto.address.neighborhood);
                fields.push(resto.price);
                resto.styles.forEach((style) => {
                    fields.push(style);
                });
                resto.types.forEach((types) => {
                    fields.push(types);
                });
                resto.address.hitos.forEach((hito) => {
                    fields.push(hito);
                });

                if(!arrayToCompare.length) {
                    restos.push(resto);
                } else {
                    arrayToCompare.forEach((field) => {
                        if(fields.indexOf(field) > -1) {
                            isRestoFiltered = true;
                        }
                    });

                    if(isRestoFiltered) {
                        restos.push(resto);
                    }
                }
            });
            console.log('ARRAY: ' , restos);
            return { code: 0, restaurants: restos }; //return restos
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log ('Error getting documents', err);
            return { code: 1, error: err};
        });
});
```

This is the array that I sent to the cloud function from Android:

```
fun getJSONRepresentation(filters: ArrayList<String>): JSONObject? {
        var filtersObj = JSONObject()
        val json = Gson().toJson(filters)
        try {
            filtersObj.put("filters", json)
        } catch (e:JSONException) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return filtersObj
    }
```

Comment: It is time to start debugging your code, add some logs to see what `data.filters` contain, like `console.log(data.filters, typeof data.filters);`

Comment: Yeah! I am new in backend, but the problem came from the JSON that I sent from the application. With the console.log I saw that it had a string type and not an object. THANK YOU!